# DOMParser attribute with no value issue

Tags: javascript, html, dom, code-snippets, domparser

I'm trying to parse HTML string into DOM:

```
str = '<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>'; 
dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html'); 
console.log(dom.body.innerHTML);
```

output this:

```
<script src="demo_defer.js" defer=""></script>
```

in the same way, string like this:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  #SecRuleEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

is fixed as:

```
<ifmodule mod_security2.c="">
  #SecRuleEngine Off
</ifmodule>
```

How to stop DOMParser from fixing HTML?
How to keep original attribute, with no default empty value?

Comment: Doubt you will be able to fix that.

Comment: There used to be a way to read back the HTML stream some 20-25 years ago... -can't recall how. Sorry. 
But right now, the best way to do it is to not parse the stream in the first place.

Comment: The premise is wrong, a DOMParser doesn't generate a string, but a document tree. Whatever you used to serialize the resulting DOM nodes did add these `=""`, for the DOM, here or not, they're the same.

Comment: @epascarello :) maybe by regex :)

Comment: @Kaiido you right! but in my specific case I need to change some node values and keep intact the rest (its for re-editing code-snippets in rich-text-editor)

Comment: And... what does that change? The DOMParser is not the culprit, it's just that you should not parse your string as DOM to do what you want. So ask about what you really are trying to do instead: you are in a X-Y problem

Answer (score 0):

well.. I don't think it's a correct way to do it, but this makeshift code might work:
for just removing '=' and ' " ' symbols from your string

```
    str2 = '<IfModule mod_security2.c>#SecRuleEngine Off</IfModule>';
dom2 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str2, 'text/html');
console.log(dom2.documentElement.innerHTML);
let result = dom2.documentElement.innerHTML;
let spRes = result.split('')

let newArr = []
spRes.filter(el => {
    if (el != '=' && el != '"') {
        newArr.push(el)

    }
})

let strAgain = newArr.join('');
console.log(strAgain);
```

Comment: dom2.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(/=\"\"/g, ''); do the same?